# Django: get the percentage of tasks completed by subproject in DetailView

Tags: python, django

I have three models, srv(the main project), project(the subprojects associated with the srv model), and finally todo(tasks associated with the project model).

```
class Srv(models.Model):
    srv_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'srv_year', always_update = True)

class Project(models.Model):
    srv = models.ForeignKey(Srv, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'project_title', always_update = True)
    resume = HTMLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    state = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null = True, default = False)
    weighted = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    todo_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'todo_title', always_update = True, null = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    deadline_date = models.DateField(null = True)
    ordering_position = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
    state = models.BooleanField(blank = True, null = True, default = False)
```

how get the percentage of tasks completed by project, whose project is associated with a main srv?

In my view

```
class srvdetail(DetailView):
    model = Srv
    template_name = 'srv_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(srvdetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        srv = self.get_object()
        srv_projects = srv.project_set.all()
        for notes in srv_projects:
            project_notes = notes.todo_set.filter(state = True)
        context['project_notes'] = project_notes

        return context
```

but I only get the tasks from one of the projects

my template.html

```
{% for project in srv.project_set.all %}
        <li style="margin-left: 50px;" class="nav-item">
          <h3><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Proyecto: {{ project }} <small> ponderación: {{ project.weighted }}% [Total: {{ project_notes }}]</small></h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-left: 75px;">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> {{ project.note_set.all.count }} Notas - {{ project.crq_set.all.count }} CRQ - {{ project.todo_set.all.count }} Tareas - {{ project.file_set.all.count }} Archivos
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

this srv has two projects:
project 1 (1 task)
project 2 (6 tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting the contents of `project_notes` for each `srv`

you probably want something like this

```
project_notes = []
for notes in srv_projects:
    project_notes.extend(notes.todo_set.filter(state = True))
```

Comment: it's a great solution, but with this I get all the tasks associated with the srv, and not per project.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your template but pass srv in the context in your view.

```
{% for project in srv.project_set.all %}
    {% for todo in project.todo_set.all %}
        {{ todo.todo_title }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

P.S. Always use `PascalStyle` for you `CBV(Class Based Views)` name format and `snake_style` for your regular `function views`. Its the standart and it improves code readability.